# How can I roll back DAO tests using scala PlaySpec and Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, transactions, slick

I'm trying to flesh out my application's abstract DAO test harness to support rolling back any test modifications to the database. I know slick supports transactions with `(db.run(<some DBIOAction>.transactionally)`, but that doesn't work as part of an abstract test class, as the db actions need to actually be run in the actual test method.

Currently, I'm working with attempting to wrap the test method with `BeforeAndAfter`'s `runTest` method and attempting to find some slick method that allows me to wrap the test execution in a transaction. It feels like the correct first step, but I'm struggling to figure out how to not interfere with regular test creation while still being able to roll back transactions (i.e. I don't want to have to manually add a DBIOAction.failure in every DB test that changes the DB state).

I've tried setting `autocommit=false` around the method, e.g.

```
db.run(
  SimpleJdbcOperation(_.connection.setAutoCommit(false)) andThen
  DBIOAction.successful(super.runTest) zip
  SimpleJdbcOperation(_.connection.rollBack()))
```

but I think the connection pool is foiling that particular method, as getting the autocommit status inside the test method returns true and the rollback doesn't do anything.

Is there anything I can do here short of hacky (manual DBIOAction.failure()) or wasteful (drop and recreate table/schema after every test) solutions?

Comment: You can also have a look at [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) for really isolated JDBC based unit tests

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm going with https://stackoverflow.com/a/34953817/1676006, but I still feel like there should be a better way.